# Is it possible to add more than one foreign key to one field in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Can I realise something like it? For example if some other field value is 'a', foreign key should be to table a, if value is 'b', it should be key to table b? I understand that it is not normal and doesn't match idea of foreign keys, but is it possible to do something to make this scheme real in fact?

Update :

I have a schema like this:

There are products. They can contain different additional fields, for example standart product can content no additional fields, but "picture" can contain fields like "author" and so on. Really "standart product" and "picture" can differ ideologically, not only because of additional fields.

There is table like "Order", that should contain link to product and other data. But when I put field like "product id", it should be data, is it standart product id, or picture id.

There can be design like table of additional fields, but there will be another problem. I can make table(id, additional_field_name) and table for mapping (id, add_field_id, product_id, field_value), but field_value can be number and can be string, so this idea is not good I think.

Comment: If you describe your exact problem, there might be a good design - such as using a third table for all the mappings.

Comment: Yes, can you describe more details? How can I add mapping between main table and table a/b? It causes the same problem. What do you mean?

Comment: You'll need to post your schema and describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  I'm sure there's a good design that will address your problem.

Comment: Updated, schema is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment & revised question:

Products

```
ID
Description
AdditionalFields_ID
```

Additional Fields

```
AdditionalFields_ID
Author
```

Then use a LEFT JOIN, so that your query only pulls additional fields *when they exist* (like when the product type is a picture).

```
SELECT *
FROM Products P LEFT JOIN AdditionalFields A ON P.AdditionalFields_ID = A.AdditionalFields_ID
```

If you want a better answer than that, you're going to have to provide some real examples of your table structure & data in your question.

Comment: It is not problem of selection. Imagine there is no selection. It is just problem of structure of db

Comment: You originally asked if you can put foreign keys from multiple tables into a single column in your parent table, the answer is yes, you *can* (not that you should, just that you can).  If your problem is something else -- I'm reading your revised question -- it sounds like you want to link to an 'additional fields' table, but only when it's for a picture, not a standard product, then I've revised my answer for that case...

Comment: Thank you, I think it is enough

Answer (score 2):

As stated, no you can't do that. You'd need to have two separate columns. Besides, interpreting the value of a column based on the value of another column doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 0):

For foreign key constraints, you'd need to use separate nullable columns, one for each potential foreign key relationship.

You could hack this together with check constraints, but you're likely better off with separate columns, both from a performance standpoint and from a consistency standpoint.

Comment: It is not good idea to add fields to table like "a_id" and "b_id", because there can be a lot of tables like a and b, and i will need to add filed for every table i think(

Comment: You may want to post more schema detail so people can better understand what you're asking.  Are you sure you want them all in one table, or would you be better off with multiple intersection tables?